# Smart Contract test wont passed event though the value that needed to pass to the expect block already exist

Tags: hardhat, async, chai

So as the title suggested i tested a smart contract (ERC721) but the the test wont pass. I am using hardhat environment for testing, that is hardhat-waffle and chai library. Here is the smart contract and the testing script

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract Depression is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
using Counters for Counters.Counter;

Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

constructor() ERC721("Depression", "DEP") {}

function safeMint(address to, string memory uri) public onlyOwner {
    uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
    _tokenIdCounter.increment();
    _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
}

// The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
    internal
    override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
{
    super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
}

function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
    super._burn(tokenId);
}

function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
    public
    view
    override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
    returns (string memory)
{
    return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
}

function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
    public
    view
    override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    returns (bool)
{
    return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
}
}
```

and here is the script for testing

```
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import chai from "chai";
import { solidity } from "ethereum-waffle";
import { Depression__factory, Depression } from "../typechain";

chai.use(solidity);
const { expect } = chai;
tokenAddress: string = "0xb962471ea0ff5db1d775374f8af342267326fbdc";

describe("Unit Test", () => {
it("VotingNFTContract", async () => {
try {
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();

  const tokenInstance = new Depression__factory(deployer).attach(tokenAddress);
  // const toMint = ethers.utils.parseEther("1");
  const toAddress = await deployer.getAddress();
  const beforeAmount = await tokenInstance.balanceOf(toAddress);
  const beforeAmountNumber = beforeAmount.toNumber()
  const tx = await tokenInstance.safeMint(toAddress, "http://localhost/api/token/");
  await tx.wait();
  const afterAmount = await tokenInstance.balanceOf(toAddress);
  const afterAmountNumber = afterAmount.toNumber();
  console.log("zap test", beforeAmount.toNumber(), afterAmount.toNumber());
  expect(beforeAmountNumber).to.lessThan(afterAmountNumber);
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error VotingNFT Deploy", error);
}
});
});
```

Heres the result of the test

```
$ yarn test
yarn run v1.22.5
npx hardhat test
No need to generate any newer typings.

Unit Test
  zap test 29 30
  Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.45.222.162:443
  Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.45.222.162:443

1) VotingNFTContract
Done in 115.79s.
```

I already use async await for the asynchronous function like balanceOf, and even already got the values in the console.log that i put, but somehow the expect block wont accept the values and then the test timedout. Any idea what i did wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out its because of the gas reporter package that i enabled, when i disable it, the test run successfully.